# Category For Pages In WordPress

Tags: categories, pages, performance

I need to categorize search result of WordPress, I have done that through adding categories to posts and custom post types. Now, only pages are listing without any category, I think it is possible to add category to pages as well, but I am not aware of its consequences(including performance).

Kindly you share your thoughts and experience.

Thank you

Comment: As I have already stated to your questionon SO, the `page` post type are not meant to have categories, and none of the page related functions are set up for this functionality. You must think ahead and decide if you are going to need more functionality for pages with categories

Answer (score 0):

You can add categories and pages with a hook

```
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );
```

Comment: ,thank you, I wonder why they didn't add it by default.